# Error prompts if data entered correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Creating a script to prompt alert if all number entered are zeros. Script is working correctly but through JS error in firebug console if number entered correctly.

How could i solve this without error prompt.

Code -

```
jQuery("#EventPhone").focusout(function(){
   var $this = jQuery(this);
   var phoneNum = ($this.val()).toString();
   var count1 = phoneNum.match(/0/g).length || "";
   var phoneNumLen = phoneNum.length
   if( phoneNumLen == count1 )
   {
   alert('All numbers in a phone number cannot be zero!!');
   $this.val("");
   }
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8XmpG/

Comment: what do u mean by this sentence : **but through JS error in firebug console if number entered correctly.**

Comment: Actually it's strange that you cannot have 0 in the phone number.

Comment: your phoneNum.match(/0/g) expression is getting you null

Comment: @RápliAndrás - he doesn't say no zeros.  He says it can't be *all* zeros

Comment: Shouldn't || "" be applied to phoneNumb instead of count1? Like `(phoneNum.match(/0/g) || "").length`

Comment: you forgot `;` after this `var phoneNumLen = phoneNum.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you have error in this line:

```
var count1 = phoneNum.match(/0/g).length || "";
```

because `phoneNum.match(/0/g)` could be null, so, if you check it first like this:

```
var count1 = (phoneNum.match(/0/g) && phoneNum.match(/0/g).length) || "";
```

everything will be ok.

Check for space:

```
var phoneNum = ($this.val()).toString().replace(' ', '');
```

Comment: So count1 may be "", even if it works because of conversions I suppose it's not his intended behavior...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** (if characters are allowed)

use this code - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XmpG/5/)

```
jQuery("#EventPhone").focusout(function(){
   var phoneNum = parseInt($(this).val().trim().replace( /\D+/g,''));
   if(phoneNum === 0 )
       alert("All numbers in a phone number cannot be zero!");
});
```

if characters are not allowed, use this code- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XmpG/2/)

```
jQuery("#EventPhone").focusout(function(){
   var $this = jQuery(this);
   var phoneNum = $this.val().trim();
   var phoneNumber = parseInt(phoneNum);
   if(phoneNum == phoneNumber && phoneNumber !== 0 ) // don't use phoneNum === phoneNumber 
   {
       alert("Right Number");
   }
    else{
        alert('Wrong Number');
        $this.val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Phone number doesn't need to be a valid number (it _may_ contains letters and spaces too). Besides few small errors what's wrong with his original implementation?

Comment: @Adriano Updated the answer to take letters and spaces in the number too.

Comment: Thx ..i approved yours :)

Comment: Sorry Not true :( check - 0978780788

Comment: @RohitAgrawal well yes it is but it's handled correctly (digits cannot be all zeros) so I +1ed

Comment: @Adriano just for info..do phone numbers contain letters as well?

Comment: @Trialcoder yes, in some countries it's allowed. It's pretty tricky because each letter represents just a number (for example 123-ABC is an _alias_ for 123-222 'cause all these letters are on the "2" char) but sometimes someone express them in that way (and your users may wish to enter them in the way they read them, without _translation_). Moreover they may contain special characters too (not just # and *) but if you do not deal with GSM you may not need to handle them.

Comment: @Trialcoder 0978780788 is accepted as correct number by my code

Comment: @Trialcoder Usually I store them as string and I use country specific validation code (or no validation at all for "unknown" countries). When possible you can even avoid to ask this to your user because phone number has the international prefix (you may use it as entry in a dictionary for regex validation) or you can get his domain (for web applications) through his language/location.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal I copy/pasted "0978780788" in http://jsfiddle.net/8XmpG/5/ and it prompts error

Comment: @Trialcoder No dude its not prompting any error, i crosschecked thrice

Comment: @Adriano are you getting error in my code for the number "0978780788"?